# courier-mta (esmtpd) only delivers messages to /var/lib/courier/tmp

Tags: debian, smtp, mail-transport-agent, courier

I swear that courier-mta was working before, but now it has stopped working.

The problem first started out with getting "submit: Permission denied" errors and I was unable to send emails to the machine.

I chmod'd `/var/lib/courier/tmp` (via `chmod 771 /var/lib/courier/tmp`) which fixed this.

But, now all the messages are stuck in `/var/lib/courier/tmp/NNNNNN` and never get migrated to `$HOME/Maildir` .

I cannot figure out what moves the files from `/var/lib/courier/tmp` to `$HOME/Maildir` so that I can use courier-pop.

What does the moving?

Note that my /etc/courier/courierd has `DEFAULTDELIVERY=./Maildir` in it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, the Debian version of **courier** must be really broken.

Amazingly, this fixed it:

`$ sudo chown courier /usr/lib/courier/courier/submit
$ sudo chmod u+s /usr/lib/courier/courier/submit`